# What does this "printf" command do?

Tags: command-line, bash

I was going through a tutorial and there I came across a command:

```
printf "%(%s)T"
```

The output of this command is:

```
1454299615
```

Could anybody please tell me what is this command and what the output means?

Comment: This seems to be shell dependent.  Is your `printf` a builtin?  `/usr/bin/printf` on Ubuntu 14.04 gives an error: `printf: %(: invalid conversion specification`.  If you're using `bash`. Try `man bash` for builtin documentation.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's a way to express the formatted time by `printf`.

The format is:

```
%(FORMAT)T
```

Where `FORMAT` is defined by `strftime(3)`.

So to get the epoch time (Time in seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC), we need `strftime(3)` format `%s`:

```
printf "%(%s)T\n"
```

Note that you also need `\n` at the end to add a newline as `printf` (unlike `echo`) does not add it by default.

**Example:**

```
$ printf "%(%s)T\n"
1454300377

$ printf "%(%Y-%m-%d)T\n"
2016-02-01

$ printf "%(%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S)T\n"
2016-02-01 10:20:27
```

---

Just for the sake of completeness, you can also use `date` command in a similar `strftime(3)` formatted manner to get the time:

```
$ date '+%s'
1454300542

$ date '+%Y-%m-%d'    ## Short form: date -I
2016-02-01

$ date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
2016-02-01 10:22:47
```

**NOTE**: This behavior is specific to `bash`'s and `ksh`'s  built-in function `printf`, and doesn't work with `/usr/bin/printf` , `csh`, and `zsh` built-ins.

Comment: @rtecxs I have moved your edit in a different place just to keep things clear..thanks anyway :)

Comment: Is this feature documented?  I didn't see it in the `printf(1)` man page.

Comment: @NateEldredge `printf` is a builtin here (although the external one has the same behavior)..check `help printf` ..